# Verify identity from contents of FedAuth cookie

Tags: security, sharepoint

When logged into a SharePoint Communication Site there is a cookie called **FedAuth** which contains, among other things, the identity of the user logged in.

It looks like this (slightly altered for security purposes):

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SP>V3,0h.f|membership|1003bffdacf190@live.com,0#.f|membership|firstname.lastname_contoso.com#ext#@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com,131604770000000,0,131609704914049,0.0.0.0,2051,dbd7d0da-4288-53-8d24-4c5a5ee08b16,,V2!1003BFFDA6ACF0!13160477577,7dbe409e-04-5000-19b9-3a71d0adb64b,7dbe409e-84-5000-19b9-3a71d0adb64b,,0,ZiikuQ
RjoJTFRD9InzwRFdmbMImfQmQHoD2Iwy9RCwEFcVdhTOdfnu17R9AOpOTgf2L4skuKeCR7oymh3rCNqgxCP5TSMEZ/6WW7SxVVSgLvQbHUS/rCZHWWxHQzVs+oaeJlKfSViVD1kGP4rROZh6G/wIiotZ4pfypb1/BMNPZthvhjybZTTaLr/CMJ7H8FkYNpgPgSf2K95yj7njRD4NJHGoL+NsoaGf+MkoXQRzQyhOWfgVLWT
fCZNQidHRXY4AonaXanJvL2fc7BGxPk0C1lC0xem6
r4h439LCYdqRfC4ZSz95ilIeLdMN8mR/caAoaODn9Aj5hb5w==</SP>
```

Now my question is, if I send this XML document to a custom API service developed by me, is there any way I can verify the contents and trust it?

Is there some signature hash in the encoded portion of the document that I can verify against a certificate or something like that?